# When loading from string to checked listview, the foreach skips characters

Tags: vb.net

I have a string, My.settings.prohibitions, full of 1's and 0's; they correspond to which items of a checked listview should be checked and which should not. I tried using the following code to check items on the listview according to the values in the string, but it didn't work; the even numbered items were always unchecked, but the odd numbered items did get checked correctly.

```
For Each setting As Char In My.Settings.Prohibitions
        If setting = "0" Then
            ListView1.Items(My.Settings.Prohibitions.IndexOf(setting)).Checked = False
        Else
            ListView1.Items(My.Settings.Prohibitions.IndexOf(setting)).Checked = True
        End If
Next
```

Edit: This does not work either:

```
        Dim x As String = My.Settings.Prohibitions
    For y As Integer = 0 To 7
        If x(y).ToString = "1" Then
            ListView1.Items(y).Checked = True
        Else
            ListView1.Items(y).Checked = False
        End If
        y += 1
    Next
```

Comment: You'll want to use a `For` loop here, not `For Each`. Increment an index variable and use that with `IndexOf()`.

Comment: I tried doing something like that, but the same problem occurred.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd(v=vs.110).aspx, `IndexOf` will return you the first occurrence of the specified Unicode character in this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
For index As Integer = 0 To My.Settings.Prohibitions.Length - 1
    ListView1.Items(index).Checked = My.Settings.Prohibitions(index) = "1"
Next
```

Comment: Your code resulted in an exception for some reason. I changed it to `        For index As Integer = 0 To My.Settings.Prohibitions.Length
            If My.Settings.Prohibitions(index) = "1" Then
                ListView1.Items(index).Checked = True
            Else
                ListView1.Items(index).Checked = False
            End If
            index += 1
        Next` and it still had the same issue. Maybe it's something to do with listviews.

Comment: @leugen9001 - I modified my code to declare the `index`. You should need to do the `If` statement as `My.Settings.Prohibitions(index) = "1"` evaluates to `True` or `False` anyway. You also don't need the `index += 1` as the `For` loop does that for you. The exception was because I forgot the `- 1`.